# PHP repeats the code after pressing submit

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a verification page that sends a randomly generated code to the users email using a python script after the user types the verification code it will be compared with the code generated from the script and if correct then redirect to another page if not then the code will print wrong and the user should try again .... the problem is every time the user presses submit the code is sent by email which means when I press submit this line will be executed again

```
$addr = shell_exec("python test.py $email $code ");
```

tried to use **exit()** and **die()** and nothing happened

```
<?php
session_start(); 
echo "E-mail has been sent to " ;
echo $_SESSION['email'];
echo $email , "   ";
$_SESSION["code"];
$email = escapeshellarg($_SESSION['email']);
$code = escapeshellarg($_SESSION['code']);
$code = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9]/", "", $code);
$addr = shell_exec("python test.py $email $code ");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<body>  
<h2>E-mail Verfication</h2>
<form method="post" action="">  
Name: <input type="text" name="verf" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit">  
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $verf1 = escapeshellarg($_POST['verf']);    
    $verf2 = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9]/", "", $verf1);
    if ($verf2 == $code) {
        echo "Correct!";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location='finish.php';</script>"; exit;
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $block = shell_exec("./block.sh $ip ");
    } else { 
        echo "Wrong!";
    }
} else {
    echo "please fill the verification";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying i have found a solution by putting this line

```
$addr = shell_exec("python test.py $email $code ");
```

on a page before this form and this will execute the code only once

Answer (score 0):

`$addr = shell_exec("python test.py $email $code ");` code is executed every time when page is loaded. You can add condition prior to this code.

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit2'])){
  $addr = shell_exec("python test.py $email $code ");
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer this will make the code run again when i press submit i don't want this i found another solution